# Get last page number from HTML

Tags: bash

I have a page pagination that look like this in HTML:

```
<span class="nav">Go to <b>1</b>, <a href="page-2.html">2</a>, <a href="page-3.html">3</a>, <a href="page-4.html">4</a>, <a href="page-5.html">5</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="page-2.html">Next</a></span>
```

What I want to get is the last page number (so in this example "5"). How I can do it in Bash? Thank you for help.

Comment: Also -- is this HTML, or XHTML? (Matters for purposes of determining the namespace). If you're not sure, is there a `xmlns=` higher in the document?

Comment: There's no xmlns= in code, grep tag removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a solution that only considers numbers given as the text associated with links inside of `<span class="nav">` (assuming `in.html` as your input file):

```
xmllint --html --xmlout - <in.html \
| xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//span[@class="nav"]//a' -v 'text()' -n \
| egrep '^[[:digit:]]+$' \
| sort -n \
| tail -n 1
```

This uses [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (included with modern Linux distributions) to convert your HTML to XML, and [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) (not always included, but [generally](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xmlstarlet) [packaged](https://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xmlstarlet) [for](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/tools/text/xml/xmlstarlet/default.nix) [common](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/textproc/xmlstarlet/Portfile) [distributions](http://brewformulas.org/Xmlstarlet)) to search that XML.

Comment: First part is possible with xmlstarlet, too: `xmlstarlet format --html --dropdtd in.html`

Answer (score 1):

If there are only numbers of the pages only numbers in the text, then you can do it like following

```
egrep '[0-9]+' -o | sort -r -n | head -1
```

it will match numbers from the text, than sort it and take the first one (highest). You can modify the regexp if you want so be more specific. Better approach would be deffinitely possible in python using [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) where you can traverse through the DOM like in jQuery.

**EDIT** added `-n` to the command (+1 @CharlesDuffy)

Comment: Without `-n`, `sort` can be inaccurate for numbers; for instance, an ASCII sort considers `20` a larger number than `100` (because `2` has a higher value than `1`).

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the HTML is always conform your input:

```
sed 's/page-/\n/g' | sort -n | tail -1 | sed 's/.html.*//'
```

(`sed 's/page-/\n/g'` puts a newline just before the page number. `sort -n` sorts numerically; the lines that do not start with a page number get sorted on top. `tail -1` selects the line with the highest page number and the `sed 's/.html.*//'` strips-off all the non-pagenumber stuff)